# Regex is failing for Range values in Laravel PHP Unit Testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I tried to make a regex with below condition:

```
-90 < latitude < 90

-180 < longitude < 180

Should have 6 decimal points.
```

and my regex for both as follows:

```
Latitude : /^-?(0|[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)\.{1}\d{6}$/

Longitude : /^-?(0|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\.{1}\d{6}$/
```

Maximum test passed through this. But when I try this in Php Unit

```
Latitude : 10.000000 , Longitude: 10.000000 // Got Failed

Latitude : 0.000001 , Longitude: 0.000001 // Got Failed

Latitude : 0.000000 , Longitude: 0.000000 // Got Failed
```

I want to include these 3 options also. I am using this regex in larval 5.6 (PHP).

Also when I do like this it's start working in unit test.

```
Latitude : "10.000000" , Longitude: "10.000000" // Got Succeed

Latitude : "0.000001" , Longitude: "0.000001" // Got Succeed

Latitude : "0.000000" , Longitude: "0.000000" // Got Succeed
```

If I am trying through Postman it's working for both cases. But while doing in Laravel PHP unit testing it's not working.

My Validation Rules is :

```
public static $fieldValidations = [
        'serial'    => 'required|unique:panels|size:16|alpha_num',
        'latitude'  => array('required','numeric','between:-90,90','regex:/^-?(0|[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)\.{1}\d{6}$/'),
        'longitude'  => array('required','numeric','between:-180,180','regex:/^-?(0|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\.{1}\d{6}$/'),
    ];
```

My Php Unit Testing Code is

```
public function testStoreFailureLatitudeLongitudeAllZeroDecimalCase()
    {
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/panels', [
            'serial'    => 'AAAABBBBCCCC1234',
            'longitude' => 10.000000,
            'latitude'  => -20.000000
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }

    public function testStoreFailurePrecisionFloatDecimalValueCase()
    {
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/panels', [
            'serial'    => 'AAAABBBBCCCC1234',
            'longitude' => 0.000001,
            'latitude'  => 0.000001
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }

    public function testStoreFailurePrecisionFloatDecimalValuewithZeroCase()
    {
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/panels', [
            'serial'    => 'AAAABBBBCCCC1234',
            'longitude' => 0.000000,
            'latitude'  => 0.000000
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }
```

These are the 3 cases where it got failed and with same values through postman it works.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateLatitude($lat) {
  return preg_match('/^(\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/', $lat);
}

function validateLongitude($long) {
  return preg_match('/^(\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/', $long);
}
```

it fails for 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001

Comment: I am testing latitude abd longitude seprately. Can you write separate regex for both.

Comment: Also got failed on 0.000001

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for Latitude you could use:

`^-?(?:[1-8][0-9]|[0-9]|90)\.\d{6}$`

And for Longitude you could use:

`^-?(?:1[0-7][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]|180)\.\d{6}$`

Note that you can omit `{1}`,  for `0|[0-9]` you could use just `[0-9]` and if you are not referring to the captured group you can use a non capturing group `(?:` for the alternation.

Comment: Nope. Got failed for all 3 cases. By omiting {1} also not working.

Comment: So your tests pass when you wrap the values between double quotes?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the question is about how to get your unit test working? Because your regexes the are matching what you intent to match.

Comment: You might add your code to the question how you have written the test

Comment: I have no experience with unit testing with Laravel, but could it be that you specify numeric and that using a regex it expects a string?